# Protractor retrieve all row with filtered column

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I want to retrieve all rows that I have filtered in the 3rd column. I have attached a picture for the reference structure of the site, here is the actual site http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/

```
    //I found this online, but its not working for me it still retrieve all the data from the table
    tablefil(){
        //third column id like to filter
       var name = "11";

        // This is like element.all(by.css(''))
        return $$("table[class='table']").filter(function(row) {
          // Get the second column's text.
          return row.$$("td[class='ng-binding']").get(3).getText().then(function(rowName) {
            // Filter rows matching the name you are looking for.
            return rowName === name;

          });
        }).getText().then(function(text){
            //Display rows that fits my filter above
           console.log('\n'+text+'\n')
        }) 
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Heb.png
```

Comment: There does not seem to be an image attached, is there meant to be? Also is it correct to say that you want the contents of all rows returned that contain '11' in the third (result) column?

Comment: Im sorry, stackoverflow did not allow me to attached the image but please see the link below the codes, yup that right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues in your code:

1) Incorrect css selector to find all rows of table. The correct one: `table[class='table'] tbody > tr`

2) The array index start from '0', thus get the third column should use
   `row.$$("td").get(2)`

```
tablefil(result){

  return $$("table[class='table'] tbody > tr")

      .filter(function(row) {

        // find out which row's Result is equal to argument: result

        return row.$$("td").get(2).getText().then(function(text) {
          return !result || text.trim() === result;
        });

      })
      .each(function(row){

        // read the text of 2nd column: Expression on matched row

        row.$$("td").get(1).getText().then(function(text){
            console.log('expression: ' + text)
        });

        // or if you want to print the Expression and Result together
        row.$$("td:nth-child(2),td:nth-child(3)").getText().then(function(texts){
            console.log(texts[0], '=', text[1])
        });  
      })
}


tablefil() // will print all rows
tablefil('11') // will only print row's Result == 11
```

Comment: thanks, but what if I only wanted to retrieve the expression column,this wont work for me    var name = "11"
    return element(by.css("table[class='table'] tbody > tr")).element(by.css("span[class='ng-binding']")).filter(function (row) {
      return row.$$(("td[class='ng-binding']")).get(1).getText().then(function (text) {
        return text === name
      })
    }).getText().then(function (text) {
      console.log(text+'\n')
      let split = text.toString().split(" ",100)
      let size = split.length;
      console.log(size)
    })